# Changing matplotlib text color to white (#FFFFFF) interferes with image output

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have some code that makes a cropped image output of a matplotlib text object, but if I change the text color to white, it won't crop the image correctly.

```
        t = plt.text(0.001, 0.025, r"$%s$" % text, fontsize = size)
        t.set_color("#FFFFFF")

        plt.axis('off')
        plt.tight_layout()

        with io.BytesIO() as png_buf:
            plt.savefig(png_buf, pad_inches=0, transparent=True, bbox_inches='tight')
            png_buf.seek(0)
            image = Image.open(png_buf)
            image.load()
            inverted_image = ImageOps.invert(image.convert("RGB"))
            cropped = image.crop(inverted_image.getbbox())
            cropped.save('out.png')
```

It works with `t.set_color("#FFFFFE")`, but not with `t.set_color("#FFFFFF")` or `t.set_color("white")`.

What is happening?

Comment: What do you mean "won't crop the image correctly"?  If you make the text white on a white background, whatever ImageOps is won't know that there is any text there.  It just sees white pixels

Comment: I see, but the background isn't really white, it is transparent, I guess I could tell the devs this behavior so they could do something for this specific case.